# Centos 6.3 can't connect to ethernet

Tags: networking, centos

I've just installed Centos 6.3 and I'm having trouble with my eth0 connection.

After I installed Centos 6.3 there was no ifcfg-eth0 file, so I made one.

inside my eth0 file I have:

```
DEVICE=eth0
IPADDR=xxx.xxx.x.xxx
NETMASK=xxx.xxx.xxx.x
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
HWADDR=xx.....
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

When I run the cmd

```
# service network start
```

it brings up the loopback interface and the eth0 interface. When I enter ifup eth0 it says 'file exists'.

I can't ping to this box and it has no ethernet connection.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try manually setting up the IP address with ifconfig? Assuming the device is eth0 -  #ifconfig eth0 xxx.xxx.x.xxx netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.x up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the `system-config-network` utilty to get your `ifcfg-eth0` file in the right format and define the gateway, DNS resolvers, etc.

You can run the `service network restart` command following that.

After that, the normal troubleshooting options apply... See if you can ping your gateway from the host. Same for the DNS servers.